# How to transition background-position in tailwind (without using transition-all)

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I’m trying to make the `bg-left` transition to `bg-right` on hover with transition. I know I can use `transition-all`, but I’ve had some issues with it. I tried updating the Tailwind config file with `transitionProperty: { position: background-position }`, but it didn’t work. Does anyone have any ideas for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values for `transitionProperty` need to be valid values for `transition-property`. With:

```js
property: background-position,
```

You are trying to do a mathematical operation of subtraction of the variable `background` and `position`, which would evaluate to a number and this would not be a relevant value for `transitionProperty` since as of writing, there are no CSS properties that consist of solely as a numerical key. More likely, `background` and/or `position` are not defined in the scope and the statement would cause a JavaScript error.

Instead, consider passing the property identifier as a string for the value of the `property` key:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      transitionProperty: {
        position: 'background-position',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="bg-left bg-[url(https://picsum.photos/300/80)] w-20 h-20 transition-position hover:bg-right"></div>
```